# mindstorm NXT bluetooth developer docs

Tags: bluetooth, nxt, lego-mindstorms

So the mindstorm NXT provides fairly user friendly bluetooth communication, which works if you just need to communicate robot to robot, or directly control the robot without much programmability.  However my engineering club wants to be able to control the robot a little more dynamically from the computer, but we want to keep the same default firmware.  The only problem is I can't figure out how to communicate with the brick over bluetooth.  I think LEGO used to have a developer sdk which had docs and stuff for usb, bluetooth, etc.  But it has since been replaced with the ev3 stuff (http://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/downloads/download-software).  So does anyone know if there is some way I can get documentation on the nxt bluetooth protocols or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since they are no longer available from LEGO, I have made them available on my web server.

http://files.lechnology.com/lego/mindstorms/nxt/